# Xcode 9 / 10 resets project navigator state

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode10

Usually Xcode project navigator saves open/closed state of the project navigator folders, so when you open the project you always see the same state as before. However it's not the case in one of my projects in `Xcode 9`. Every time I open it Xcode project navigator opens some folders I don't need and closes the others. Is there any way to fix this annoying bug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an easy workaround: exit Xcode and delete appropriate `xcuserdata` folder:

```
YourProjectName.xcodeproj/xcuserdata // no Cocoa Pods
YourProjectName.xcworkspace/xcuserdata // for Cocoa Pods
```

This effectively resets all user settings for the project, but Xcode would be able to start saving them again. [More info on those folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13453842/2432781).

Xcode 10 update: same bug, same workaround

Comment: This immediately resolved the issue for me, and it stayed resolved.  Big relief, as I've got a workspace with a half dozen different large projects in it.

Comment: For those of you using Cocoapods, I have found this tip only works if you delete the xcuserdata directory in **both** xcworkspace and xcodeproj